# Problema com Switch case no JS usando options no HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, switch

Estou fazendo um código para praticar switch case no JS mas não esta funcionando, está indo direto para o default, alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver o problema?

Primeiro em HTML:

```
<main>
    <section>
        <label>Valor da compra:</label>
        <input type="number" name="totaç" id="total" 
        placeholder="Informe o valor total">
    </section>
    <br>
    <form id="formulario">
        <section>
            <label>Selecione seu codigo:</label>
            <div>
                <select id="codigo">
                    <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                    <option value="1">1 - para Cliente Comum</option> <!--5% de desconto-->
                    <option value="2">2 - para Cliente VIP</option> <!--15% de desconto-->
                    <option value="3">3 - para Funcionário</option> <!--10% de desconto-->
                </select>
            </div>
        </section>
        <br>
        <button onclick="calcular()" type="submit">Calcular</button>
    </form>

    <h2 id="resultado">Resultado..</h2>
</main>
```

JavaScript:

```
const form = document.getElementById('formulario');
form.addEventListener('submit', prevenção) //adicionar um tipo de evento ao clicar em converter

let tot = document.getElementById('total')
let total = Number(tot.value)

let cod = document.getElementById('codigo')
let codigo = Number(cod.value)

let result = document.getElementById('resultado')

let opçao = cod.selectedIndex

function prevenção(e){
    e.preventDefault() //para nao atualizar a pagina automaticamente

    if (!tot.value || tot == 0){
        window.alert("Informe o valor Correto.")
        return
    }else if (cod.value == ''){
        window.alert("Selecione um codigo para ver o desconto.")
        return
    }
    calcular()
}

function calcular(cod){
    switch(cod){
        case 1:
            opçao == '1 - para Cliente Comum'
            var desc = total - (total * 5 / 100)
            result.innerHTML = `Desconto de 5%, valor total a ser pago: ${desc}`
            break
        case 2:
            opçao == '2 - para Cliente VIP'
            var desc = total - (total * 15 / 100)
            result.innerHTML = `Desconto de 15%, valor total a ser pago: ${desc}`
            break
        case 3:
            opçao == '3 - para Funcionário'
            var desc = total - (total * 10 / 100)
            result.innerHTML = `Desconto de 10%, valor total a ser pago: ${desc}`
            break

        default:
            result.innerHTML = `Operação inválida`;
    }
}
```

Comment: `function calcular(cod)` - aqui vc definiu que a função `calcular` recebe o parâmetro `cod`. Mas quando ela é chamada (dentro da função `prevenção`), vc faz `calcular()`, ou seja, não passa nenhum parâmetro. E quando vc não passa nenhum, o valor acaba sendo `undefined`, por isso ele não entra em nenhum `case` (creio que deveria ser `calcular(cod.value)`). Fora isso, essas linhas `opçao == '1 - para Cliente Comum'` não servem para nada (elas fazem uma comparação e o resultado não é usado, então essas linhas estão "perdidas")